# Semantic meaning of the <mark> tag

Tags: html

I read the explanation on the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element) but for me the definition isn’t satisfying. Can anybody paraphrase this?

As I understand, it should be used in cases when a certain part of a text references to another context, like e.g. another text part or a search string I entered.

I don’t get the examples with the quotations—where’s the referential meaning when highlighting a part of a quotation just to gather the readers’ attention or mark a part of a quotation to emphasize it?

Comment: Ever used one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlighter)?

Answer (score 1):

To say it with the words of [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com) and also to reference to a got article about it: "*[Draw attention with mark](http://html5doctor.com/draw-attention-with-mark/)*".

From w3c.org: [4.6.19 The mark element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element):

> The mark element represents a run of text in one document marked or highlighted for reference purposes, due to its relevance in another context. When used in a quotation or other block of text referred to from the prose, it indicates a highlight that was not originally present but which has been added to bring the reader’s attention to a part of the text that might not have been considered important by the original author when the block was originally written, but which is now under previously unexpected scrutiny. When used in the main prose of a document, it indicates a part of the document that has been highlighted due to its likely relevance to the user’s current activity.

The last part from the article mentioned in the beginning says something on the semantics of this tag as well:

> **Differences from strong and em**
>
> Previously, you may have used em and strong for adding emphasis or importance, respectively, to portions of text. mark differs from these two as it is used purely for highlighting the relevance of a piece of text to the user and/or page’s content. In the past you may have used em and strong for this purpose, which was arguably valid at the time due to the lack of a better element, but the introduction of mark simply means their use will be more strict.
>
> Use strong when you need to indicate the importance of a piece of text, such as an error or warning message, and em should be for adding emphasis to text, stressing words to adapt the meaning of a sentence.